# Magento 2 customer can't log in but I can

Tags: magento2

My customer reported me, that he can't log in to shop because he's s getting almost blank page:

[image]

I tried to log in as customer using my account and had no problem with this. But my customer was saying the problem is still there. So I asked him about his login and password. When I tried to log in using his credentials I had the same error. I noticed when I press "Log in", cpu usage of MySQL goes to 100%.

[image]

What could be wrong? There must be some kind of problem with account, but I have no idea how to debug it.

Comment: It can be due to some specific data stored in the customer section. It can be : `Orders`, `Customer wishlist`, `Items in cart`. I would suggest you to look into admin. add the same items to your cart and then try logging in from your account as first step. If doesn't solve then look into specific items. Most likely it is due to some customizations

Answer (score 0):

Log in with your customer account, and share with us what the console logs displays, inside the DevTools.
There, once we see the errors we could advice better.

Also, one more way to find whats wrong is to run xdebug and go step by step and you will see what is going wrong.